# Excel Transpose Assistance Needed

Tags: excel, formulas

I currently need to provide a monthly report in excel from this mysql output

[image]

But in the report I send the data is arranged as follows

[image]

So currently its a manual process but was wondering if there was a transpose function I could use to expedite this?

Comment: It's called "[Pivot Table](https://support.office.com/en-GB/Article/Create-a-PivotTable-to-analyze-external-data-db50d01d-2e1c-43bd-bfb5-b76a818a927b)" in Excel.

Comment: Thanks but for some reason that link does not work for me

Comment: Here is the url: https://support.office.com/en-GB/Article/Create-a-PivotTable-to-analyze-external-data-db50d01d-2e1c-43bd-bfb5-b76a818a927b

Comment: Thanks, it was a pivot I needed and all good now. I would like to award this to you but you only commented. Do you want to provide the actual answer and I can award?

Comment: @pnuts No, I wasn't. But I wouldn't post an answer anyway because it's just silly. Answers of that magnitude are automatically converted to comments, for good. Feel free to post something better/bigger though.

Comment: @pnuts Nah, the appearance is that SO cannot be bothered to act on this question either, with 33 views in 3 months.